# how to display an arraylist of items within an object?

Tags: java

i want to display a list of screens in an array alongside the name of that screen.

here is the code for the Menu class

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
Screen [] screen;


    public void menu()
    {


        screen[0] = new Screen("SRN-1",{"The Hunger Games: Mockingjay, Part 2", "Love the Coopers", "The 33"}, {6.78, 7.89, 5.75}, {21,23,26});
        screen[1] = new Screen("SRN-2",{"Kilo Two Bravo ", "Spectre (2015)", "The Peanuts Movie (2015)"}, {7.45,8.37,8.95}, {12,76,75});
        screen[2] = new Screen("SRN-3", {"Goosebumps (2015)", " Bridge of Spies (2015)", "  Hotel Transylvania 2"}, {8.37,8.58,9.58}, {63,63,78});
        screen[3] = new Screen("SRN-4", {"  The Last Witch Hunter (2015)", "Paranormal Activity: The Ghost Dimension (2015)", "The Intern (2015)"}, {5.76,7.37,9.47}, {63,84,13});

        prt("");
        prt("Select a screen: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < screen.length; ++i){
            prt("Press " + i + " to select " + screen[i].getName();
        }

        int inputNo = input.nextInt();
```

and here is the code for the screen class. What is wrong with my constructor?

```
public class Screen {

    String srnName;
    String [] movieList;

    double [] cost;

    int [] seats;

    public Screen(String srnName, String [] movieList, double [] cost, int [] seats)

   {this.srnName = srnName;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.seats = seats;
    this.movieList = movieList;}

    public int[] getSeat() {return seats;}
    public String getName() {return srnName;}
    public String[] getMovie() {return movieList;}
    public double[] getCost() {return cost;}


}
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem? Are you getting a compilation error? A runtime error? The wrong result?

Comment: Stackoverflow will not run your code, it requires what is the problem your facing with the code and the code that your trying to achieve it.please make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You must define a size of array.

```
Screen[] screen = new Screen[4];
```

**2.** If you pass array as parameter you must add type:

```
screen[0] = new Screen("SRN-1", new String[]{"The Hunger Games: Mockingjay, Part 2", "Love the Coopers", "The 33"}, new double[]{6.78, 7.89, 5.75}, new int[]{21,23,26});
```

Or you can initialize variable to pass as parameters:

```
String[] movieList1 = {"The Hunger Games: Mockingjay, Part 2", "Love the Coopers", "The 33"};
double[] cost1 = {6.78, 7.89, 5.75};
int[] seats1 = {21,23,26};
screen[0] = new Screen("SRN-1", movieList1, cost1, seats1);
```

**3.** You have forgotten about closing parenthesis:

```
 prt("Press " + i + " to select " + screen[i].getName());
```

**Ad 1.**
You can use List instead od array. Then you will not have define size array fixed.

```
List<Screen> screen = new ArrayList<>();
screen.add(new Screen("SRN-1", new String[]{"The Hunger Games: Mockingjay, Part 2", "Love the Coopers", "The 33"}, new double[]{6.78, 7.89, 5.75}, new int[]{21,23,26}));
// etc. you can add multiple objects
```